# Redirecting using location.href does not set the authentication cookie

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am developing a web application that authenticates user using an AJAX post.

User is correctly authenticated but when after the redirect occurs to other page, using location.href, the authentication cookie is not set until I click a link in the new page loading another page.

This the login JS function:

```
function performLogin(loginUrl) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: loginUrl,
        data: $('#frmLogin').serialize()
    }).done(function (data) {
        location.href = data;
    }).fail(function (jqXHR) {
        showError(jqXHR);
    });
}
```

By using the browser development tool, I can see that the `Set-Cookie` header is present in the response of the login method in the server.

Is there a way to solve this or should I get the `Set-Cookie` header value and set the cookie by calling a JS function?

Regards
Jaime